# extract degree, average degree from Graph class

Tags: python, networkx

Has anybody tried to implement a software to  to extract degrees, average degrees from Graph Class of NetworkX? I am not asking for implemented methods in networkX which is stable. I am asking here for scratch level implementation.

Here is what I have tried so far (not sure if that is correct)?

```
for i in range(3, 9):
    G = nx.gnp_random_graph(i, 0.2) #Returns a G_{n,p} random graph, also known as an Erdős-Rényi graph or a binomial graph.
    #print(len(G))
    #print(len(G.nodes()))
    from collections import *
    import collections

    class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
        pass

    m=[list (i) for i in G.edges()]

    flat_list = [item for sublist in m for item in sublist]
    counterlist = OrderedCounter(flat_list)
    degree_sequence=sorted(sorted(counterlist.values(), reverse=True))
    degreeCount=collections.Counter(degree_sequence)
    print("degreeCount:", degreeCount)

    #deg, cnt = zip(*degreeCount.items()) #Returns the average degree of the neighborhood of each node.
    #print(deg, cnt)

    nodes = len(G) 
    count_Triangle = 0 #Initialize result 
    # Consider every possible triplet of edges in graph 
    for i in range(nodes): 
        for j in range(nodes): 
            for k in range(nodes): 
                # check the triplet if it satisfies the condition 
                if( i!=j and i !=k and j !=k and
                        G[i][j] and G[j][k] and G[k][i]): 
                    count_Triangle += 1
                    print(count_Triangle)
```

when I count triangle this way I keep on getting `Key error` which is because I know the index I am passing is not correct. I thought G is a dict object. Can't figure out.

Also if I try to extract `deg, cnt` above from which I thought was solution to get average degree, I keep getting error when the dictionary is empty.

Answer (score 2):

### For triangle counting

- the dict-like access `G[u][v]` operates on the edge data in the graph `G`, so the keys in the dict `G[u]` are not (in general) all other nodes in the graph; though the keys in the dict `G` do include all nodes in the graph.
- If you want to pursue this form of indexing, you would probably be better off generating an adjacency matrix, which has n x n elements for an n-node graph.  Then all queries `A[i][j]` for i in the range [0, n] will be valid; and the return value will be 0 if there is no edge.
- also look at itertools, which will make your code cleaner..

```py
for i,j,k in itertools.combinations(xrange(n), 3):
    # a generator of all unique combinations of [0,1,2,3,4]
    # this already excludes the cases where i==j, i==k j==k
    print(i,j,k)
```

though be careful because there are various functions in this package that are quite similar.

Here is some code that gets you the triangle count here

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

T1 = []
T2 = []

n = 7
p = 0.2
reps = 1000
for r in xrange(reps):
    G = nx.gnp_random_graph(n, p)

    A = nx.adj_matrix(G);

    t = 0;
    for (i,j,k) in itertools.combinations(xrange(n), 3):
        # a generator of all unique 3-combinations of [0,1,2,...,n]
        if i==k or i==j or j==k:
            print ("Found a duplicate node!", i,j,k)
            continue # just skip it -- shouldn't happen
        if A[i,j] and A[j,k] and A[i,k]:
            t += 1
    T1.append(t);

    # let's check we agree with networkx built-in
    tr = nx.triangles(G)
    T2.append(sum(tr.values()))    

T2 = [t /3.0 for t in T2]; # divide all through by 3, since this is a count of the nodes of each triangle and not the number of triangles.

plt.figure(1); plt.clf()
plt.hist([T1, T2], 20)
```

Here you see that the triangle counts are the same (I put a log scale on the y axis since the frequencies of the higher triangle counts are rather tlow).

[image]

## For degree-counting

It seems that you need a clearer picture of what degree you want to compute:
- This is an undirected graph, which means that if there is an edge between u and v, then both of these nodes should be at least degree-1.  Your calculation counts edges only once.

Secondly, the graphs you are producing do not have many edges, especially for the smaller ones.  With p=0.2, the fraction of 3-node graphs without any edges at all is 51%, and even 5-node graphs will have no edges 11% of the time.  So an empty list is not indicative of a failure.

The average degree is very easy to check, either using the graph attributes:

```
2*G.number_of_edges() / float(G.number_of_nodes())
```

or the built-in per-node degree-calculator.

```
sum([d for (n, d) in nx.degree(G)]) / float(G.number_of_nodes())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code. First, `node` should be list of nodes in the Graph `G` not the length of the nodes in the Graph. This will make sure that your logic works for all graphs ( even with Graph whose node do not start with index 0). Also, your for loops should change accordingly, like this

```
nodes = G.nodes() #<--- Store the list of nodes 
count_Triangle = 0 #Initialize result
# Consider every possible triplet of edges in graph

for i in nodes: #<---------Iterate over the lists of nodes
    for j in nodes: 
        for k in nodes:
```

Next, you do not access the edges of the Graph like indices. You have to use [has_edge()](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.has_edge.html) method because, incase the edge is not present, the code will not fail.

So your `if` statement  becomes :

```
if( i!=j and i !=k and j !=k and
                    G.has_edge(i,j) and G.has_edge(j, k) and G.has_edge(k, i)):
                count_Triangle += 1
                print(count_Triangle)
```

Putting all this together, your program becomes:

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import *
import collections

for i in range(3, 9):
    G = nx.gnp_random_graph(i, 0.2)
    class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
        pass

    m=[list (i) for i in G.edges()]

    flat_list = [item for sublist in m for item in sublist]
    counterlist = OrderedCounter(flat_list)
    degree_sequence=sorted(sorted(counterlist.values(), reverse=True))
    degreeCount=collections.Counter(degree_sequence)
    print("degreeCount:", degreeCount)


    #Store the list of nodes 
    nodes = G.nodes()

    count_Triangle = 0 #Initialize result
    # Consider every possible triplet of edges in graph


    for i in nodes:    #<---------Iterate over the lists of nodes
        for j in nodes:
            for k in nodes:

                # Use has_edge method
                if( i!=j and i !=k and j !=k and
                        G.has_edge(i,j) and G.has_edge(j, k) and G.has_edge(k, i)):
                    count_Triangle += 1
                    print(count_Triangle)
```